# I'm learning recusive function and I just don't understand the result

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void draw(int h);
int main(void)
{
    int height = get_int("Height: \n");
    draw(height);
}

void draw(int h)
{
    if (h ==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    draw(h - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

So it printed out     "#
                       ##
                       ###
                       ####"
(Space is for each row)I dont understand the draw(height), it keeps subtracting till 0, but how the for loop print the hash like that? Like how it print in increasing row after the recursive function subtract it to 0? Please explain how it works step by step, thank you in advance.

Comment: Walk through it in a debugger to see how it behaves, especially with respect to the stack.

Comment: It prints in increasing rows because it makes the recursive call *before* it prints the current row. So the first time it prints is when it has recursed to `h==1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call to `draw()` to execute the printing lines will be `draw(1)`, because you are calling `draw(h - 1)` at first, therefore the calls will be stacked in the stack and then executed before the `for`.

Trying to simplify the sequence:

```
=> draw(3);
==> Calls: draw(2);
===> Calls: draw(1);
====> Calls: draw(0) <=== return to [draw(1)];
===> draw(1): run the for ("#") <== return to [draw(2)]
==> draw(2): run the for ("##") <== return to [draw(3)]
=> draw(3): run the for ("###") <== return to first caller
```

Result:
`# ## ###`

---

To a better understanding, you can switch the `draw(h - 1)` and `for` order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    printf("#");
}
draw(h - 1);
```

You will get:
`### ## #`

Comment: Wait, so it climbs back up but not from up down? This is where I don’t understand. I thought that each time draw is called it make a row in decreasing order from top down like 4321 not 1234 and the for loop prints from top to bottom.

Comment: The key concept is that `drawn(3)` not finish executing until `draw(2) ... draw(0)` finished, because execution waits inside `draw(3)` at the call to `draw(2)`. It's how stack and recursion works (first-in last-out). Search YouTube for "recursion and call stack", surely there are many very graphical instructional videos, is much easy to explain with graphics/animations 

Comment: Please **"Mark as Answer"** ✅ my response if it was useful to you. Have a good learning! 

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Comment: Also one more thing, why does it return to draw 1 after reaching 0, is it because of return;?